# How to set pre-select dropdown with reactive forms? Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

i need to set preselect dropdown on edit. I am using reactive forms.
Check my code:

Answer (score 1):

You bind your option with `[ngValue]="test.value"` but you set this.test[2] in your formGroup.

Replace : `valueTest : [this.test[2]]` by `valueTest : [this.test[2].value]`

Also, replace `[ngValue]` by `[value]`

also, you can try this to check was going on :

```
compareObjects(o1: any, o2: any) {
  console.log('o1 : ', o1);
  console.log('o2 : ', o2);
  return (o1===o2)
}
```

and

```html
<select 
class="form-control"   
formControlName="valueTest"
[compareWith]="compareObjects"
>
```

Comment: try to replace [ngValue] by [value] ?

Comment: Hmmm no work...there is maybe somethink another problem..